# Stack Exchange RSS feeds do not exclude ignored tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-watching, feed, ignored-tags

In order to get feeds with only the tags `[php]`, `[css]` and `[javascript]`, I use this:

[https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=**php+or+css+or+javascript**&sort=newest](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=php+or+css+or+javascript&sort=newest)

But how do I get the same feed to **exclude tags I'm not interested in** (for instance, `[jquery]`)?

I tried to use the minus syntax suggested [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/10/tags-and-tags-or-tags/), but it does not seem to work:

[https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=php+or+css+or+javascript+**-jquery**&sort=newest](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=php+or+css+or+javascript+-jquery&sort=newest)

The `[jquery]` questions continue to show up.

If it's possible to use it for feeds, do you know what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mixing of `or` and `not` gets ambiguous because there is no support for explicit grouping, eg

`(foo or bar or baz) and not shazam`

not the same as

`foo or bar or baz and not shazam`