# Feed containing everything but a given set of tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, feed

I read several StackExchange sites for new questions strictly via feeds. I have broad interests, but some questions are definitely not relevant. I am currently reading the all-questions feed (`e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/feeds`), but that is just a bit too much of a firehose.

How can I get a feed of ***all* questions on a given site *except* a given set of tags** (preferably my ignored tags, so that I can update the set easily)?

There are a number of ways to get feeds of a union of tags (+ in URLs, filters) but I haven't seen any way to subtract tags other than the way mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61941/stack-exchange-rss-feeds-do-not-exclude-ignored-tags) which is implied to not work but no details or workaround are given.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I understand where you're coming from, but this currently isn't possible, and very likely will never be supported.

The reason is because such a set of questions is an *unrestricted* set, which means running the database query for it will be very inefficient (maybe not for a single user, but multiply by thousands across the network, and we're in big trouble). This is the same reason why searching for questions by tag requires at least 1 tag to be explicitly *included* before you start excluding tags.

Unless your list of ignored tags is really long, the best workaround (crappy as it is), is simply to get a feed of *all* the newest questions. If you have lots of ignored tags, you may do better to create an exhaustive list of tags you want to *include* in the feed.

Comment: +1, and it's certainly understandable, but, as a workaround... *ewww*?

Comment: How about, instead of performing a query specifically for these questions, filtering the results for the all-questions feed as they're streamed out for this feed request? (I recognize that this might cause varying numbers of items in the feed and I think that would be all right.)

Comment: @Kevin: That would be... unpredictable, and difficult from a support perspective. Having said that, depending on how you're consuming the feed, you could do this filtering yourself -- the feed contains tag information for each question (search for `<category>` tags in the raw XML).

Comment: Hm, yes. I don't have a feed reader that will filter for me, but I [have previously used local-web-server-and-XSLT glue](http://kpreid.livejournal.com/6603.html) which I could use to generate a filtered feed. If I write up such a filter I'll post it here as an answer.