# Is it possible for the RSS feed to erroneously publish questions that don't match the query?

Tags: support, tags, feed, integration

I have [a bot](https://slack.com/help/articles/218688467-Add-RSS-feeds-to-Slack) transferring results from an RSS feed of Stack Overflow questions with specified tags into [Slack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slack_(software)).

RSS feed: https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=manatee.json+or+json-everything&sort=newest

Until a few months ago, it was working perfectly.  However, recently it has been spamming unrelated questions into Slack.

Questions like *[Xcode: How to create alias for already added image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75236921/xcode-how-to-create-alias-for-already-added-image)* are being added to the channel. That very obviously doesn't have one of the requested tags.

I get spurts of 30 of these each time this happens. This has been happening for at least a couple months (I can't see past 3 Jan this year in my Slack). Fortunately, posts aren't very common: maybe once per week.

But if you look at the feed content, you see that the only questions it contains are ones with one of the tags. For example, the first one is [Get Line/Col info from System.Text.Json.JsonElement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70563051) titled "Get Line/Col info from System.Text.Json.JsonElement" and published on 2022-01-03 (a year ago).

I raised this with Slack support, and they suggest that the feed momentarily contains these questions, which the bot picks up and posts.  Is it possible for the feed to just change content like that?  Might that be what's happening?

Comment: It probably stems from the same cause, yes, though I'm not entirely sure it's a _duplicate_.  They seem to be getting questions from the same (unrequested) tag, whereas mine are seemingly random.  There's not a solution there, really, either; just a bug report.

That said, I wasn't sure whether mine's a bug, so I put `support`.  Feel free to change to `bug` if you feel that's apt.

Comment: This bug is actually being tracked at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/422443/tags-behaving-oddly-this-new-years-day/423056#423056.  Maybe the "duplicate" response can be updated to reflect that?

Comment: [Stack Exchange RSS feeds do not exclude ignored tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61941/stack-exchange-rss-feeds-do-not-exclude-ignored-tags) is not an appropriate duplicate of this question.  The one I linked above is.